# Why can't my code load RNotify?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm an Arch Linux user for some years and I loved to use pacman-notifier to keep me up to date for updating my box.

A couple of weeks ago pacman-notifier stopped working for me with the following message:

```
$ pacman-notifier
/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require': cannot load such file -- RNotify (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/pacman_notifier/gui/gtk.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/pacman_notifier.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/bin/pacman-notifier:3:in `<main>'
```

First I thought the RNotify package isn't in the right place, so I search for it:

```
$ locate rnotify
/opt/kde/include/kdirnotify.h
/opt/kde/include/kdirnotify_stub.h
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-libnotify-0.5.1/doc/ext/rnotify_c.html
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-libnotify-0.5.1/ext/rnotify.c
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-libnotify-0.5.1/ext/rnotify.o
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-libnotify-0.5.1/ext/rnotify.so
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-libnotify-0.5.1/lib/rnotify.so
```

But I think with the output I got they are in the right spot.

I also tried to examine the mentioned `/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/pacman_notifier/gui/gtk.rb` but as I've really no clue what to search for I gave up.

Can anybody give me a hint to solve my problem?

Comment: No, should I use that?

Comment: no, it is because if you do, rnotify would be loaded from a different path

Comment: What does `locate RNotify` (or `locate -i rnotify`) show? I think there should be a `RNotify.rb` alongside the `rnotify.so` in the gem’s `lib` dir.

Comment: That's correct.

Content:  
`# cat /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ruby-libnotify-0.5.1/lib/RNotify.rb  
=begin  

RNotify.rb  

Luca Russo <vargolo@gmail.com>  
Copyright (LGPL) 2006 - 2012  

=end  

require 'gtk2'  
require 'rnotify.so'  

module Notify  
  VERSION = "0.5.1"  
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that ruby-libnotify does not support Ruby 2. This may not be the answer you want, but you may check out the [libnotify gem](https://github.com/splattael/libnotify) .  It seems to me to be very similar but more actively maintained, and it supports Ruby 2.